# Getting all users and their last login via graph API

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to export all users data including last login date. I am following this article:

https://morgantechspace.com/2021/09/find-last-login-date-for-all-azure-ad-users-using-powershell.html

By using this call:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,signInActivity

PS:

```
$Url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Add System.Web for urlencode
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

# Create body
$Body = @{
    client_id = $AppId
    client_secret = $AppSecret
    scope = $Scope
    grant_type = 'client_credentials'
}

# Splat the parameters for Invoke-Restmethod for cleaner code
$PostSplat = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Method = 'POST'
    # Create string by joining bodylist with '&'
    Body = $Body
    Uri = $Url
}

# Request the token!
$Request = Invoke-RestMethod @PostSplat

$ApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,signInActivity"

$Header = @{
    Authorization = "$($Request.token_type) $($Request.access_token)"
}

While ($ApiUrl -ne $Null) #Perform pagination if next page link (odata.nextlink) returned.
{
    # Fetch all security alerts
    $SecurityAlertsRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ApiUrl -Headers $Header -Method Get -ContentType "application/json"

    $SecurityAlerts = $SecurityAlertsRequest.Value

    foreach($User in $SecurityAlerts){
         if($User.signInActivity.lastSignInDateTime) { 

            $test = [DateTime]$User.signInActivity.lastSignInDateTime 

    } Else {$null}


    }

    $ApiUrl=$SecurityAlertsRequest.'@odata.nextlink'
}

$SecurityAlerts
```

I connect via an app reg:
[image]

However signInActivity is always null for all users. Is it not possible to get all users with graph API including last signin?

Comment: Might be a copy/paste error, but your `$ApiUrl` should either be single-quoted or the `$` symbol needs to be escaped.

Comment: WOW pretty sharp eye!!! Not a copy paste, but that was the problem! Thanks alot, can you paste an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` in the MS Graph REST URLs is required as part of the query string. You'll need to either escape it with backtick `, or use single quotes:

```sh
$ApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?`$select=displayName,signInActivity"
```

Comment: How to get sign in activity of single user?

Comment: @kudlatiger To stay within the question, you can filter the graph result by display name to get the activity for a single user. For anything else, try `Get-MgUser` or ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

Two key points is that first you need to have the `AuditLog.Read.All` permission scope added to your application permissions. Second, `SignInActivity` is a part of the "beta" version of the Microsoft Graph SDK API. You have to change your Microsoft Graph profile to the "beta" version before you connect in order to access the beta version of the API
I find it's easier to use the new [Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/overview?view=graph-powershell-beta) PowerShell module to get this information:

```
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'AuditLog.Read.All'
$user = Get-MgUser -UserId '123-...-abc123' -Property 'SignInActivity'
$user.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime
```

Comment: Thanks your input is appreciated. I connect via an app registration that has AuditLog.Read.All permission. I would also like to get users in larger batches rather than taking one user at the time. If you look in my url I am using beta? Or am I wrong here?

Comment: I added permissions for my app reg. to original post.

Comment: @ThomasSegato "beta" version **only** applies when dealing with the SDK API. You are using simple REST methods, and I confirmed `SignInActivity` is included by default.