# Graph API - How to get Last login date of the logged on user in Angular using Azure AD Authentication

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

We have angular 13 based application. We are using Azure AD Authentication. When user hit's the Portal URL, he is asked to key in credentials. After successful authentication, user is redirected to a landing page. On top of the page, we need to display the last login date for the logged on user.

I have been looking into https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
but I could not find anything.

Any pointers would be helpful.

best regards,
SP

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=javascript#example-3-get-users-including-their-last-sign-in-time

If you are connecting to a C# api that does the request to graph :

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Select("displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity")
    .GetAsync();
```

HTTP : `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity`

JavaScript :

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

let users = await client.api('/users')
    .version('beta')
    .select('displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity')
    .get();
```

Following is an example of the response :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users(displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity)",
  "value": [
    {
      "displayName": "Adele Vance",
      "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@contoso.com",
      "signInActivity": {
        "lastSignInDateTime": "2021-06-17T16:41:33Z",
        "lastSignInRequestId": "d4d31c40-4c36-4775-ad59-7d1e6a171f00",
        "lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "lastNonInteractiveSignInRequestId": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Alex Wilber",
      "userPrincipalName": "AlexW@contoso.com",
      "signInActivity": {
        "lastSignInDateTime": "2021-07-29T15:53:27Z",
        "lastSignInRequestId": "f3149ee1-e347-4181-b45b-99a1f82b1c00",
        "lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime": "2021-07-29T17:53:42Z",
        "lastNonInteractiveSignInRequestId": "868efa6a-b2e9-40e9-9b1c-0aaea5b50200"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I will check about what you have mentioned.

Comment: API version is beta, is that safe to use?

Comment: It typically isn't recommended to use Beta stuff in production not just because of safety concerns but overall stability that it will always perform correctly. I have had no choice to use beta one time in production with no problem but that was only on a small application that was internal facing.

Comment: To be allowed to query the SignInActivity you need additional permissions: AuditLog.Read.All, this is not standard the case for user accounts, and will require addition permissions for the application.

Comment: @Charilie V all you need to setup is on the behalf of flow with the api that calls graph and have the account that actually calls graph on behalf of the user to have the AuditLog.Read.All permission set ....

Comment: I have given permission to the scope "AuditLog.Read.All" and I am getting 401. No clue what permission is missing...

Comment: I have given permission to the scope "AuditLog.Read.All" and I am getting 401. I am using MSAL for Azure Authentication and I could see that Authorization token is not being passed. This is strange, I used another API from V 1.1, the same works without any issue.

Comment: Are you doing your calls from angular to your own api which your api then calls the graph api. Or are you making calls directly from your angular app to the graph api.

Answer (score 0):

The following stackoverflow post answers your question: [Getting all users and their last login via graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71485129/getting-all-users-and-their-last-login-via-graph-api)

Please note that you need additional API permissions for your Angular App to perform this. The default API permissions will not work.

Are you looking for when the User used his/her MS account to log into your application only? It might be easier store the unique MS id (together with the current DateTime) that you receive from MS Graph API, in your own database / api and use that in your application?

Comment: We are not storing the information in DB as you have mentioned. I am searching, if there is a mechanism offered by Graph API.

Comment: I need "last Login time" for the logged on user, not a list of users.

Comment: The graph api will give the lastLoggedIn time for ALL applications. Not only your application. If that’s what you want to know, use the API. Also; you can use **me** instead of **user** to get info for the current user.

Comment: Plenty of other roles are required to be added to hit the mentioned endpoint which we cannot. So this end point is not going to work.