# Azure AD: Last signin of a user (older than 30days)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I want to identify inactive users.
however - 30 days are sometimes not long enough

Now i found that in the Azure AD Portal one can see Azure Logins older than 30 days
[image: User properties]
but when i open the signin logs - this signin is not visible (because it's older than 30 days)
[image: signin logs empty]

I can via Powershell query the SigninLogs. No problem there.
BUT how can i query the Last Signin as shown in the Azure AD GUI?

any idea?

BR

Comment: if you can get the SigninLogs why not just sort the newest and get it? also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71485129/getting-all-users-and-their-last-login-via-graph-api

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadauditsigninlogs?view=azureadps-2.0-preview

Comment: You can set up a diagnostic pipeline to stream the logs to Log Analytics or Data Explorer for a greater retention period of your sign-in logs

Comment: Thanks for your ideas - but the signin logs only provide the last 30days and the GUI shows older dates.
even without log analytics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **As per [MsDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/reference-reports-data-retention#how-long-does-azure-ad-store-the-data) Sign-in logs will be visible based on the type of Azure AD license currently having on portal. In Azure portal you can't find sign-in logs more than 30 days**

I have a tenant with `Azure AD Premium P2` license like below:

[image]

I have one user with last sign-in as April 18th like below:

[image]

When I tried to get sign-in logs of this user by selecting last one month in filter I got same response like below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can make use of Microsoft graph to fetch that user last sign-in log like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_id>?$select=id,displayName,signInActivity
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer provided me the direction to go to!

THX!!

using 
```$users = Get-MgUser -Property SignInActivity ```
provides available Data even via the Graph Powershell Module